# C# Search txt file by ID and delete whole line which in file is separated by \n

Tags: c#, console-application, text-files

I want to search my txt file by ID and remove all data which is related to this ID.
My txt file is formatted like below:
235678876
John
Doe
[www.niezdam.com](http://www.niezdam.com)

565678053
Lucy
Patel
[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

where each user is separated by empty line and each word in a string is in new line. I tried this code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the item ID want to remove: ");
        string itemId = Console.ReadLine();

        var editedData = lines.Where(line => !line.StartsWith(itemId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !line.EndsWith(" "));

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, editedData);
```

So if I find user with, for example ID 235678876, I want to delete "235678876 John Doe www.niezdam.com" and my code works fine, but it delete only ID, not all related data...
How can I improve my code to get what I want? Please, give me anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count - 4; i += 5)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith(itemId))
    {
        // Removes 5 lines, (ID, Firstname, Lastname, Link, Newline)
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            lines.RemoveAt(i);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one-liner

```
lines.RemoveRange(lines.IndexOf(itemId), 5);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me also how to reverse the whole process. What if this ID would be at the end of each string, not on a start. I mean ow to reverse these two loops, I tried to do that, but its not my level yet... I also tried this piece od code:  `int startsWith = lines.IndexOf(itemId);  int endsWith = lines.IndexOf(website);  if (startsWith != -1 && endsWith != -1)  lines.RemoveRange(startsWith, endsWith);`  but I am not sure how to grab this blank space.

Comment: If you have the structure like [ FirstName, LastName, Website, ID, NewLine ] the following code will work:
```int startIndex = lines.IndexOf(itemId) - 3;
lines.RemoveRange(startIndex, 5);```
Note that I don't check for that the index was found or not, you have to add the checks to see if ```startIndex``` is -1 or not.

Comment: I will do that, thank you very much. I do not have to add that it works.. ;)